# Normalize [normalize]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[normalize](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/normalize) is used mostly to mean equalizing volume.  However, some questions use the tag to mean standardize the format of a document or spreadsheet.  Although there are not yet any examples, the term could also refer to normalizing statistical data.

Recommendation: Change [normalize] to [normalize-volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/normalize-volume) or [equalize-volume](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/equalize-volume).  Create a new tag: [standardize-format](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/standardize-format) or [standardize-layout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/standardize-layout) and migrate the couple of questions that used the tag in that way.  Ignore data normalization for now.  If there is no plain [normalize], it won't get used for that.

Comment: Tag is useless. It should just be deleted.

Comment: [volume] and [volume-mixer] tags already exist, so you might be right.  There is also a [layout] tag (undefined).